# MVVM / ViewModel / User controls / DataContext / Command - Design Issue/Discussion

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a User Control that displays/manages one or more Addresses for an entity (employee, business, etc).

I have leveraged this User Control from various views - encapsulating the UI of an address within the control.

I have several ViewModels that hold/expose an Address Collection from various different perspectives - each of which is usually managed by a different ViewModel (one ViewModel for each View)

I have passed the appropriate DataContext to the user control, meaning that although I have various ViewModels that expose the Address Collection - I can pass the appropriate context via the DC Binding.

My question then becomes where do I put the Command Logic for adding and removing addresses?  I do not want to put commands that are identical in each view model, as that would be simply repeating code.

Being new to MVVM, would I just create a class with an IAddressCommand interface - and then stub out the commands in each of the ViewModels?  Do I just encapsulate a view model, within another Viewmodel?

Thoughts?

Regards
Richard

Answer (score 1):

If the commands are the same for each type of address, then consider having a base ViewModel from which Address ViewModels inherit. The common command code can be placed in the base class.

Comment: Sounds good, but I already have a base class for all ViewModels and multiple inheritance won't work!

Comment: @codputer You can introduce an AddressViewModel that inherits from your  exiting 'ViewModelBase', and then change your existing classes to inherit from that.

Comment: That works, but does not address the problem of the DataContext of the component is set at a different level of the object graph, than the command members set directly off the ViewModel.  if I move the DataContext up the object graph, the field bindings have to refer to a level deeper in the tree.

Comment: @codputer In MVVM the `ViewModel` is the `DataContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a service (not a ViewModel) that can tie these components together if you are certain you need a 1:1 approach with regard to your ViewModels:View. You would then make a call to the service within the ViewModel which would take care of adding/removing addresses from the underlying collection. This service can then be consumed by multiple ViewModels as needed.

If you are willing to adjust your design; make use of a single ViewModel or scale it back which could provide the ability to add/remove addresses from the underlying collection and can then be consumed and used by multiple Views.

IMHO going the first route and abstracting this workload into a service would be the better approach; although either would suffice.

Comment: How do you propose that I bind the command buttons to the service?  The DC sets the context of the bindings, and the command buttons are higher in the object graph than the field bindings. 

ScottGu, in the FireStarted, mentioned that in Silverlight 5 there would be an Ancestor (?) binding clause that would search for the command binding up the DC tree - I think this situation is exactly why they are introducing the new clause.

Comment: @codputer Bind the commands to the ViewModel just as you are now but at the point of action on the command you would make a call to the service; don't try to bind to the service itself.